# Arduino secure mqtt example not subscribing to topic

Tags: mqtt

I am wrestling with the below example.
I have a RasPi on the network running Mosquito with username and password credentials setup and I know this is working.

If I load the below example, I can confirm the following:

- It does connect to my Wi-Fi
- It does connect to the mqtt broker
- It does publish the example data (confirmed in serial monitor window and MQTTBox running separately)
- But, it never receives a message on the subscribed topic.

I also have a VM with Mosquito running without credentials and if I swap to that, then messages sent on the subscribed topic do appear in the serial monitor.

I am using an ESP8266 D1 and am perplexed. Any thoughts appreciated.

```cpp
/***************************************************
  Adafruit MQTT Library ESP8266 Example

  Must use ESP8266 Arduino from:
    https://github.com/esp8266/Arduino

  Works great with Adafruit's Huzzah ESP board & Feather
  ----> https://www.adafruit.com/product/2471
  ----> https://www.adafruit.com/products/2821

  Adafruit invests time and resources providing this open source code,
  please support Adafruit and open-source hardware by purchasing
  products from Adafruit!

  Written by Tony DiCola for Adafruit Industries.
  MIT license, all text above must be included in any redistribution
 ****************************************************/
#include <ESP8266WiFi.h>
#include "Adafruit_MQTT.h"
#include "Adafruit_MQTT_Client.h"

/************************* WiFi Access Point *********************************/

#define WLAN_SSID       "my_network_ssid"
#define WLAN_PASS       "my_network_ssid_password"

/************************* Adafruit.io Setup *********************************/

#define AIO_SERVER      "ipaddress for a raspberry pi only running mosquitto with username and password enabled - tested and working"
#define AIO_SERVERPORT  1883                   // use 8883 for SSL
#define AIO_USERNAME    "mosquitto_username"
#define AIO_KEY         "mosquitto_password"

/************ Global State (you don't need to change this!) ******************/

// Create an ESP8266 WiFiClient class to connect to the MQTT server.
WiFiClient client;
// or... use WiFiClientSecure for SSL
//WiFiClientSecure client;

// Setup the MQTT client class by passing in the WiFi client and MQTT server and login details.
Adafruit_MQTT_Client mqtt(&client, AIO_SERVER, AIO_SERVERPORT, AIO_USERNAME, AIO_KEY);

/****************************** Feeds ***************************************/

// Setup a feed called 'photocell' for publishing.
// Notice MQTT paths for AIO follow the form: <username>/feeds/<feedname>
Adafruit_MQTT_Publish photocell = Adafruit_MQTT_Publish(&mqtt, AIO_USERNAME "/feeds/photocell");

// Setup a feed called 'onoff' for subscribing to changes.
Adafruit_MQTT_Subscribe onoffbutton = Adafruit_MQTT_Subscribe(&mqtt, AIO_USERNAME "/mytestfeeds/onoff/");   //have changed the topic from default

/*************************** Sketch Code ************************************/

// Bug workaround for Arduino 1.6.6, it seems to need a function declaration
// for some reason (only affects ESP8266, likely an arduino-builder bug).
void MQTT_connect();

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(115200);
  delay(10);

  Serial.println(F("Adafruit MQTT demo"));

  // Connect to WiFi access point.
  Serial.println(); Serial.println();
  Serial.print("Connecting to ");
  Serial.println(WLAN_SSID);

  WiFi.begin(WLAN_SSID, WLAN_PASS);
  while (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED) {
    delay(500);
    Serial.print(".");
  }
  Serial.println();

  Serial.println("WiFi connected");
  Serial.println("IP address: "); Serial.println(WiFi.localIP());

  // Setup MQTT subscription for onoff feed.
  mqtt.subscribe(&onoffbutton);
}

uint32_t x=0;

void loop() {
  // Ensure the connection to the MQTT server is alive (this will make the first
  // connection and automatically reconnect when disconnected).  See the MQTT_connect
  // function definition further below.
  MQTT_connect();

  // this is our 'wait for incoming subscription packets' busy subloop
  // try to spend your time here

  Adafruit_MQTT_Subscribe *subscription;
  while ((subscription = mqtt.readSubscription(5000))) {
    if (subscription == &onoffbutton) {
      Serial.print(F("Got: "));
      Serial.println((char *)onoffbutton.lastread);
    }
  }

  // Now we can publish stuff!
  Serial.print(F("\nSending photocell val "));
  Serial.print(x);
  Serial.print("...");
  if (! photocell.publish(x++)) {
    Serial.println(F("Failed"));
  } else {
    Serial.println(F("OK!"));
  }

  // ping the server to keep the mqtt connection alive
  // NOT required if you are publishing once every KEEPALIVE seconds
  /*
  if(! mqtt.ping()) {
    mqtt.disconnect();
  }
  */
}

// Function to connect and reconnect as necessary to the MQTT server.
// Should be called in the loop function and it will take care if connecting.
void MQTT_connect() {
  int8_t ret;

  // Stop if already connected.
  if (mqtt.connected()) {
    return;
  }

  Serial.print("Connecting to MQTT... ");

  uint8_t retries = 3;
  while ((ret = mqtt.connect()) != 0) { // connect will return 0 for connected
       Serial.println(mqtt.connectErrorString(ret));
       Serial.println("Retrying MQTT connection in 5 seconds...");
       mqtt.disconnect();
       delay(5000);  // wait 5 seconds
       retries--;
       if (retries == 0) {
         // basically die and wait for WDT to reset me
         while (1);
       }
  }
  Serial.println("MQTT Connected!");
}
```

Comment: Have you tried listening to all topics? Just mytestfeeds/#? It's also typically not recommended to start or begin topics with a '/'.

Comment: Also, [this](https://learn.adafruit.com/mqtt-adafruit-io-and-you/help) should help pin down the issue.